# Dependency problem when upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I wanted to update r, but when trying to update it

```
 sudo apt install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.0.3-1.2004.0) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$ sudo apt install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.3 is to be installed
               Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Depends: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$ sudo apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.27-3ubuntu1.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$
```

I ran into this Problem but trying to update Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04 to then being able to update r gave me this error

```
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-foreign r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$
```

To me it seems like I can't update one without updating the other or am I just not seeing the solution

Thanks for your help in advance.

This is the message when trying your code

```
johannes@johannes-UX303UB:~$ sudo apt install r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-foreign  r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-boot : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.0-1.2004.0) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: r-api-4.0
 r-cran-class : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.0-1.2004.0) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: r-api-4.0
 r-cran-foreign : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.0.0-1.2004.0) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Depends: r-api-4.0
 r-cran-rpart : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200326-1focal) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: r-api-4.0
 r-cran-spatial : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.3.20200409-1bionic) but 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Depends: r-api-4.0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Did you by chance also switch to using the CRAN mirrors for current R?  The straight-up upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 should really work.  (I, however, update every six months).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, I have (much !!) more experience with upgrading every six month rather than every two years between LTS but when you have an error as in the last message I find the best step is to explicitly ask for the install and see the error, *i.e.*

```
sudo apt install r-cran-boot r-cran-class r-cran-foreign \
      r-cran-rpart r-cran-spatial
```

Can you try that, please? (Minus the line break I added for clarity.)

Also, and maybe 'just for now' disable the (otherwise *excellent* CRAN Ubuntu binaries from CRAN, which I also use) to ease the upgrade.  When you comment out any such entries in the `apt` config, run `apt update` the subsequent `apt-cache policy r-base-core` should show focal.  So to make the upgrade "easy" ensure you only have the last line:

```sh
edd@rob:~$ apt-cache policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: 4.0.3-1.2004.0
  Candidate: 4.0.3-1.2004.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
edd@rob:~$
```

Once your system is at 20.04, it will be easy to enable CRAN and get to R 4.0.3.

Comment: I am relatively new to this, can you explain what you mean with disabling cran in the apt config? PS. I added the terminal result for the command you recommended to my original question.

Comment: You have a mix of repos. You point to particular addons (as "4.0.0-1.2004.0" is *not* a version from Ubuntu) but you do not have the underlying R version. Hence the error. At some point you must have thought that was a good idea.  To fix, `grep -ir cran /etc/apt` and put a `#` in front of line that link to CRAN (or other non-standard repos).

Comment: Awesome!  And "all this stuff" actually works really really well ... once you put the puzzle pieces in in the right order. I wholeheartedly recommend the additional repo from the c2d4u+ repo (reference near the end of the 1st para in the CRAN README.html for Ubuntu).